# Why do we multiply by the value on the normal curve instead of the area under the curve in naive anomaly detection algorithm?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

In the naive unsupervised anomaly detection algorithm, we go through each feature and calculate the probability of getting the value. Then, we multiply the probability for each feature to calculate the net probability.

But, in multiplication, we use the actual value on the normal curve: $$\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp{\left(-\frac{(x - \mu) ^ 2}{2\sigma^ 2}\right)}$$

Shouldn't we multiply by the area under the curve for getting such an extreme value i.e. the area under the curve for $(-\infty, -x) \cup (x, \infty)$

I can imagine a scenario where the $\sigma$ is high (the curve is highly spread out) and so even the probability of getting the mean is low.

How does this work then? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to statistics.

Thanks!

Comment: I mean you could? This would then more closely resemble the way one-sided or two-sided $p$-values are defined/calculated.

Comment: @G.Bellaard Exactly. Why don't we do that? Isn't it the correct way for calculating probabilities for a normal curve?

Comment: Do you have a link or reference for this algorithm?

Comment: @Adam Learnt it in my course. But here is an online article: https://towardsdatascience.com/unsupervised-learning-for-anomaly-detection-44c55a96b8c1

Comment: The two things are the same; declaring something an anomaly when it's too extreme is the same as declaring it an anomaly when the probability is too low, it's just a different way of describing the same algorithm.